# recovery batch file to execute multiple programs and copy folders from a usb

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

so i have this USB stick that i use to backup files. after having a lot of trouble with my pc I get kind of annoyed when i need to install every program one by one, and after that copy files one by one...

To make things easier on myself, i decided to make a batch file to do all of this for me. keep in mind i am not to experienced with batch coding, and i also am newly introduced to stackoverflow.  i have microsoft technet open and multiple threads on stackoverflow to help me out but with every feature i want to add, my head just does not know what to do. this is what i have so far:

```
@echo off
title PC BACKUP
:TOP
set programA=programA.exe
set programB=programB.exe
echo starting
@echo off
start %programA%
start /W programA.exe 
start %programB%
start /W programB.exe 
xcopy "E:\recovery\sony" "C:\Program Files (x86)\sony" /c
```

E:\ would be the usb thumbdrive and C:\ would be my HDD
/c makes xcopy ignore errors

start /W programB.exe would make the batch file wait until programB.exe is closed, before starting on the next line of commands. this does work!

can anyone help me out with this? i would greatly apreciate a little example!

Comment: not 100% clear, but try add ` ""` after `start` (empty window name): `start "" %programA%`

Comment: the program starting part does work. the copying part is a bit hard. im considering moving to robocopy. a bit of research told me this is a more powerfull copying program that is integrated in windows OS

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

```
XCOPY "E:\recovery\sony" "C:\Program Files (x86)\sony" /E /H /C /R /Q /Y
```

*tested in a new batch file*
this at least keeps the cmd running, it now says this:

[image: new batch file test]

would E:\ not be the usb thumb drive in this particular situation & how would i make xcopy copy from my usb drive to my HDD?

Comment: `/I  If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.`

Comment: so it should be 
XCOPY "E:\recovery\sony" "C:\Program Files (x86)\sony" /E /H /C /R /Q /Y /I